# Can a woman marry a man her mother milk-fostered?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, rada

**Consider the following Condition**
If there are two women(sisters) let we name 'A' and 'B'. Woman A has three sons and woman B has two daughters.Woman B gave milk to woman A's first son.

Question : Is nikah halal for the first son of woman A to marry woman B's second daughter??

Comment: I had a doubt, [what about the marriage between second son of woman A and daughter of women B?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9630/marriage-with-brothers-foster-sister)

Answer (score 3):

No, Nikah is not halal between first son of woman A and woman B's any daughter.

As there is a hadith([shahih Bhukari- 3.814](http://alim.org/library/hadith/SHB/814/3)) stated that the foster relations are treated like blood relations.

It is also stated that even the nikkah with foster brother's daughter for a man is not permitted in the following hadith.

> Ibn Abbas (Allah be pleased with them) reported: It was proposed that
>   he (the Holy Prophet) be married to the daughter of Hamza, whereupon
>   he said: She is not lawful for me for she is the daughter of my
>   foster-brother, and that is unlawful by reason of fosterage what is
>   unlawful by reason of genealogy.- [Sahih Muslim Book 008, Hadith Number 3409](http://hadithcollection.com/sahihmuslim/136-Sahih%20Muslim%20Book%2008.%20Marriage/11266-sahih-muslim-book-008-hadith-number-3409.html).

It is clear that foster relations are like blood relations.

Answer (score 1):

No it is haram because they are brother dairy.

that should not marry :

1. biological mother
2. brother dairy
   etc

may be useful :)

Comment: Assalamu Alaikum, We welcome you to Islam.SE, Please add some references from hadith or quran to make your answer helpful to others. Jazakallahu Hair.

Answer (score 0):

If her mother milk - fostered the child 5 times, then he becomes the mahram of his foster-mother's children. This means that the girl cannot marry her foster-brother at any point.

However, if the mother did not milk-foster the child 5 times, he does not become the mahram of the mother's children. This means that it is permissible for the girl to marry the man.

So, your answer depends on if he was milk-fostered at least 5 times when he was a child.