# Marriage with brother's foster sister

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith, nikah, rada

It is stated that the foster relations are treated like blood relations in the following hadith.

> Narated By Amra bint 'Abdur-Rahman : That 'Aisha the wife of the
>   Prophet told her uncle that once, while the Prophet was in her house,
>   she heard a man asking Hafsa's permission to enter her house. 'Aisha
>   said, "I said, 'O Allah's Apostle! I think the man is Hafsa's foster
>   uncle.' " 'Aisha added, "O Allah's Apostle! There is a man asking the
>   permission to enter your house." Allah's Apostle replied, "I think the
>   man is Hafsa's foster uncle." 'Aisha said, "If so-and-so were living
>   (i.e. her foster uncle) would he be allowed to visit me?" Allah's
>   Apostle said, "Yes, he would, as the foster relations are treated like
>   blood relations (in marital affairs)." - [Sahih Bukhari](http://www.hadithcollection.com/sahihbukhari/81-Sahih%20Bukhari%20Book%2048.%20Witnesses/3362--sahih-bukhari-volume-003-book-048-hadith-number-814.html).

Is it permitted for a man to marry the foster sister of his brother?

Since, that woman is only his brother's foster sister, not for him.

ie,
What about marriage with blood relation's foster relation?

Comment: I think you would be okay. There's no problem marrying someone like the one you mentioned in your question. Here's a link that may help you with your question. http://alfatihoun.edaama.org/Fatawas/English/Fatawas/V5/5elevend.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [What kind of relations are explicitly forbidden in Islam for marriage?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8943/what-kind-of-relations-are-explicitly-forbidden-in-islam-for-marriage)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What women can't a man marry?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/what-women-cant-a-man-marry)

Answer (score 2):

As example, Ali has foster sister called Aisha, 
Aisha has sister called Fatima, and brother called Ahmad.
Ali has brother called Said.

Ali has now 2 Sisters and 1 Brother, Aisha and Fatima , and Ahmad, but Said is not brother of Aisha, Fatima, and Ahmad.
So Said can marry Aisha or Fatima if there is no foster sister/brother for Said (example if Ahmad is foster brother of Said, then Aisha and Fatima are sisters and not allowed to marry any of these girls).

See this : http://islamqa.info/en/113957